# JBox2d Reference Manual?

Tags: box2d, reference-manual, jbox2d

Where do i find reference manual of [`JBox2D`](http://www.jbox2d.org/) ? I was using [`fisica`](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/fisica/) which inherits [`JBox2D`](http://www.jbox2d.org/). There is [reference manual of `fisica`](http://www.ricardmarxer.com/fisica/reference/index.html) but can't find reference manual of [`JBox2D`](http://www.jbox2d.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JBox2D has been updated to use the new Box2D 2.1.* syntax, so to get at the documentation download 2.0.1 for C++ and then read the manual and the api.chm. This syntax is nearly identical to JBox2D with a few minor differences that are very obvious:

[Download Box2D 2.0.1 from this link...](http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/list)